# Passing through an ASPX file to get a file on a server ? (Webforms)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a page where i can actually upload files to 3 folders. I already protected those folders relative to roles of users in web.config. But this is not enough, i need some more validation process, i have to expose the files only to roles which is part of a group. There is 3 groups of persons and they share the same roles. So i have to access those files from an aspx where i can define this validation. Poeple MUST pass to this file in order to download files from the server. They can't access the file directly in their browser since i need to figure out which group the user come from and serve the exact files for this group.

Any ideas how i can do this ?

**Edit** : Groups are not refered to window authentification groups. Groups are a concept in my application.

Thanks.

Comment: Link file access to an active directory account? There is a lightweight protocol that can be used easily over the web.

Comment: Nah its simply a folder on the web with the asp.net membership system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you're speaking of *groups*, I assume you're using Windows authentication. If that's indeed the case, then [Request.IsAuthenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx) will tell you whether the current request comes from an authenticated user, and if it does, [Context.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) will be a valid [WindowsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.aspx) whose [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx) property will give you the name of the user and the groups he belongs to.

Then, you can perform your checks and use [Response.TransmitFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) to send the file to the client (without buffering):

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.HeaderEncoding = Response.ContentEncoding;

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
    String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", yourFileName));
Response.AppendHeader("content-length",
    yourFileSize.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Response.TransmitFile(yourFilePath);
Response.End();
```

That said, note that an [HTTP handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985/EN-US) is usually preferred to an ASP.NET page to perform that kind of work.

Comment: Groups in my application are only a concept to seperate users nothing more. I need a way to transmit files from a folder that is associated by a group.

Comment: @Rushino, so your membership provider gives you the folder where the files reside? Do the users pass the file name in the URL?

Comment: Users pass the filename into the url. It seem i figured out how to make the whole thing working. Thanks to you, example was useful. I just had to protect the folders (role protection) then with the handler i added the group protection layer then transmitting the corresponding file.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with a whole aspx page to serve just the files. Use a generic http handler instead. Your users can access a url like

MyFileHandler.ashx?fileName=File1

Then in your ProcessRequest method you can do your role validation and serve the appropriate file via `HttpResponse.TransmitFile`

Comment: This may be a good idea, however it is possible to get files inside a protected barrier set by web.config ?

Comment: @Rushino:  when you use an HTTP handler, the handler code is run before the file is transmitted.  So basically you can perform any check your heart desires and only display or allow the file for DL when your criteria is met.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to go about this.  Using HTTP handlers would probably work better for what you are trying to accomplish.

Check out: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm

This gives you more explicit control over exactly what you do when files are accessed via any method.  Once your handler is ready you can edit your HTTP handler mappings in IIS and choose your HTTP handler to allow/disallow file access.

Your handler could examine the folder of the requested URL and figure out if the user is allowed to see this file or not.  Once you figure it out it works really great.